# Current string-theory version of Big Bang

Tags: string-theory, big-bang

I always wondered what the description of Big Bang would be like in string theory.

How is it different from QFT version of Big Bang?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a QFT version of the Big Bang. QFT takes us back to the electroweak symmetry breaking, which was about 10$^{-12}$ seconds after the big bang. What happened before then isn't known, though hopefully the LHC will tell us soon. Incidentally http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_Big_Bang is an interesting related article.

String theory doesn't have a lot to say about the Big Bang at the moment. This area is known as [string cosmology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_cosmology), but it's all pretty speculative at the moment. Googling for "string cosmology bounce" finds a couple of books on Google books, e.g. [this book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=d0izBJTl7b4C&pg=PA239&lpg=PA239&dq=string%20cosmology%20bounce&source=bl&ots=vqza0xM9cH&sig=nUk0b767jllp1t1pdYNcsW4zAho&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4EOUT-HqHKW_0QW3gPXVAQ&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=string%20cosmology%20bounce&f=false) and [this review](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0207130). I don't know enough about the subject to know how this work is regarded.

[Loop Quantum Cosmology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_cosmology) predicts the universe did not shrink to a singularity at the Big Bang, but instead reached a minimum size then [bounced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bounce). So winding time back you'd see the universe shrink down then expand again. Again, most of us would regard this as pretty speculative.

Comment: It's not much more clear in loops what cosmology looks like, the bouncing idea is strange. But inflation is all long before the electroweak breaking, and it's experimentally established.